# How to make img fit div with vanilla Html & CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

**The Problem**

There is a space below the `img` in `md` screen size, and I try to get rid of it.

I've tried to add `pa-0` in class, but still can't figure out how to achieve the result.

**Restriction**

Since the whole code will be received in frontend Nuxt2 in v-html to represent the description + image. So I couldn't add CSS as well. Only vanilla html+ Some Vuetify syntax.

**Update**

This is for Nuxt2 with Vuetify, using in v-html.

**Update ver.2**

Initially there is a css attribute in the section of v-html.

```
margin-bottom: 12px;
```

But the answer is a good format to code in vanilla html.

**my code**

```html
<div class="py-6 pa-0">
  <div class="row no-gutters align-center" style="background-color: #f6f6f6">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 order-md-1 order-2 px-4 mb-1">
      <h1 class="display-1 py-8">Main Property</h1>
      <div class="align-center d-flex justify-space-between mb-1">
        <h5>Water</h5>
        <div class="mb-1"><small>And more</small></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 order-md-2 order-1">
      <img class="mx-auto" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1668277280345-f3949c1b6aa2?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1974&q=80" lazy-src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1674707735136-3d3a8720397e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=688&q=80"
        alt="test" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see a lot of utility CSS classes that are specific to a particular framework. Are you using Bootstrap for styling? If so, you might want to edit the title and tags to clarify that it's a Bootstrap question. Naming like `md` or `pa-0` doesn't mean much outside a given framework, and calling it "vanilla CSS" wouldn't help getting relevant answers.

Comment: I have updated the description. Thank you for the further question.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this sounds like an an issue with line height getting the best of things,
simply set the `font-size` of the image container to `0` and the bottom space should disappear.

```css
div {
  font-size: 0;
}
```